# Asterisk AMI tracking the inbound call

Tags: php, ubuntu, asterisk, tracking

I have an assignment, and need help in these two points.

There is ubuntu 16.04 server, the following task needs to be in PHP

1. tracking the inbound call 
   using Asterisk AMI, 
   when the incoming calls is in place, you need to track how long the  conversation took place in realtime.
2. create a mini dashboard to display the ongoing call and display the data on point 2.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It appears as though you want us to do the assignment for you. You need to ask specific question about specific coding issues.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is issue in dialplan UserEvent with all params you want submit to AMI and track ami event UserEvent.